# Picking random numbers from a smaller sample size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to use the `random.randit(0, 100)` to make a list of 10000 random values. Now, the range is smaller than the sample size. How do I work this out so I get duplicate values and a full list of 10000 integers between 0 and 100.

Comment: How would the result of calling `random.randint(0,100)` 10,000 times differ from what you want?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.random.randint` can accept a third argument being the number of random numbers you want to generate. This will fix your code and get what you need:

```
import numpy as np
your_10k_random_numbers = np.random.randint(0,100,10000)
```

Alternatively, only using python `random`

```
import random
your_10k_random_numbers = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(10000)]
```